# Difference between two classes __construct()

Tags: php, methods, between

I cannot understand what is __construct(). I can't see the differences between this two examples:

1)

```
class Person {

public function __construct($person) {
    echo $person;
} 

$person = new Person('Name');
```

2)

```
class Person {
    public function name($name) {
        echo $name;
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->name('Name');
```

Comment: Manual: [Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: constructor simply define first and required behavior on creating object

Comment: How can't you see it?
With __constructor() you can give the attributes in one line, directly. With 2nd way you have to call another function in the object Person. The difference would be... practicality

Comment: You cannot see the difference?! One is passing the argument at construction time, the other to another instance method later. Pretty clear difference IMO. You might want to clarify why you think that's not different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two examples may indeed seem equivalent, but from a single (yours, now) perspective only.

---

```
class Person { // First case : using the constructor

    public function __construct($person) {
        echo $person;
    } 
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
$person = new Person('Name');
```

In this example, you make it very clear that each and every object of class `Person` (or one of its subclasses) **must** be given a name as soon as it is created. There won't ever be a `Person` without a name, at any point in time. That's a design constraint you choose to impose on yourself (if you intend to create objects of class `Person`) or others, in the case you are sharing your code in one way or another. If one attempts to violate this constraint, PHP will hang with an explicit error/warning message. (demo : https://3v4l.org/hCXZ8)

---

```
class Person { // Second case : no constructor (equivalent to an empty constructor)

    public function name($name) {
        echo $name;
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
$person = new Person();
$person->name('Name');
```

This is a different beast : you can create an object of class `Person`, and you can display a name. You can also create a `Person` and never display a name at all. You might not even know you can, actually, if you don't set your eyes on the class code for some reason (it is common practice to give each class a distinct file).

---

In both examples I drew a comment line between the class declaration and usage, because these are two different perspectives (think they can even be two different people who cannot communicate with each other). As the class author, you translate your constraints precisely into the most explicit code you can produce. As the class user, you don't want to lose time understanding the intricacies of the class you are using : you want to create objects with minimal complexity, take advantage of the functionality with minimal overhead and learning curve, and get on with your code and business.

Answer (score 4):

In this contrived example, the second is fine.

What if `name` was a field of the class though instead of just a method that echos? What would it's value be before you explicitly set it?

To ensure fields are initialized and setup is done before an object can be used, use the constructor. If you don't need initialization, you don't necessarily need to write an explicit constructor.

Comment: Ok..I understand it now...i think....but i if you want write a small example to understand it better. Thanks you very much!

Comment: @ΜάνοςΑρβανίτης I haven't written PHP in awhile, so I was hoping to avoid writing code. I wouldn't want any mistakes I introduce to further confuse the situation. How much have you studied the use and creation of objects? If you're just starting, the purpose of the constructor may not be obvious. As soon as you begin writing more complicated objects, it should become clearer. The problem with the example you posted is there is no point in using a class in the first place. The method might as well a bare function.

Comment: It's useless to try to draw conclusions about the operation of classes from code that is misusing classes in the first place.

Comment: The truth is I do not have much knowledge on the objects. I will learn more about objects. Thanks you!